# opera position fixed to fixed elements and resize bug?

Tags: css, opera, fixed

I used 2 div's with fixed positioning, and after resize - opera doesen't redraw elements.

```
#wrapper{
    position:fixed;
    z-index:10000;
    height: auto;
    background-color: transparent;
    margin: 0;
}

#label {
    position: fixed;
    bottom:0px;
    left: 50%;
    background-color: transparent;
    z-index: 9999999;
    height: 40px;
    width: 200px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    margin-left:-100px;
}


<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="label">content</div>
</div>
```

U can see this bug here

http://jsfiddle.net/6Cm6J/1/

Just load page in Opera browser and resize window.

Pls help

Answer (score 0):

Write this css

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6Cm6J/11/)**

**css**

```
#wrapper{
    position:fixed;
    z-index:10000;
    height: auto;
    background-color: transparent;
    margin: 0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
}

#label {
    position: relative;
    bottom:0px;
    left: 50%;
    background-color: transparent;
    height: 40px;
    width: 200px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    margin-left:-100px;
}
```